# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS How do I eliminate dependency problems when upgrading the kernel from 5.15.0-88-generic to 6.6.0?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 22.04, dpkg

I get "dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration" errors when attempting to upgrade my kernel from 5.15.0-88-generic to 6.6.0-060600-generic.

How do I resolve these issues?

[Link to output of dpkg command...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhNlm.png)

Comment: The 6.2 kernel is the normal upgrade with the hwe packages for 22.04 (soon to be 6.5 when the 23.10...). I guess you could run an alpha of 24.04 in a vm to get the 6.6 kernel, but alpha versions are pretty buggy, and looking for bug submissions.

Comment: @user535733, I looked and saw that 6.6.0 wasn't a release-candidate (rc), so I deemed it "safe enough."  My other machine kernels are all 6.2.0-36-generic, and since I didn't find the exact kernel at Ubuntu, I took the highest stable version.

This version (5.15.0-88-generic) seems to freeze at random times, which becomes annoying.  Since my other machines do not do it, and the only difference seems to be the kernel, I decided to upgrade it.  I did not find 6.2.0.36 so I simply went with the newest non-rc version.

Comment: @ubfan1, my three other boxes were loaded ubuntu 22.04.3 from scratch.  The subject system was an upgrade from 18.04 LTS --> 20.04 --> 22.04 LTS.  So there were always issues with it.  I really try to avoid non-LTS releases.

Comment: @user535733, I would be interested in that, and if you can point me in the right direction, I'll figure out what it is about.  I'm all for keeping things as simple as possible.  The maintenance is a necessary evil for me, but I'd like to minimize it if possible.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04` to install the HWE kernel metapackage, which will pull in kernel 6.2 immediately. In January 2024, that will bump to kernel 6.5. You should not encounter version-conflict errors installing this metapackage, which is designed to be compatible with 22.04. If you do encounter more version errors, then you have a separate puzzle to be solved.

Comment: Please post the result as text in your question, instead of posting a link to a screenshot.